# Conflicting method when paramter is limited to AnyRef and AnyVal in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

Scala compiler detects the following two `map` functions as duplicates conflicting with each other:

```
class ADT {
    def map[Output <: AnyVal](f: Int => Output): List[Output] = ???
    def map[Output >: Null <: AnyRef](f: Int => Output): List[Output] = ???
}
```

The class type of `Output` parameter is different. First one limits to `AnyVal` and second one limits to `AnyRef`. How can I differentiate them?

Comment: The problem is that, after erasure, they would not be different. What is it that you are trying to achieve, exactly? Do you want to have a method `map` available for `AnyVal`s and one for `AnyRef`s? And the right one to be chosen automatically?

Comment: @mdm Yes. Two methods one for `AnyVal`s and one for `AnyRef`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not differentiating `AnyVal` from `AnyRef` so much as getting around the fact that both method signatures become the same after erasure.

Here is a neat trick to get around this kind of problem. It is similar to what @som-snytt did, but a bit more generic, as it works for other similar situations as well (e.g. `def foo(f: Int => String): String = ??? ; def foo(f: String => Int): Int = ???` etc.):

```
class ADT {
  def map[Output <: AnyVal](f: Int => Output): List[Output] = ???
  def map[Output >: Null <: AnyRef](f: Int => Output)(implicit dummy: DummyImplicit): List[Output] = ???
}
```

The cutest thing is that this works "out of the box". Apparently, a `DummyImplicit` is a part of standard library, and you always have the thing in scope. 
You can have more than two overloads this way too by just adding more dummies to the list.

Comment: I think the cutest thing is the word `Dummy`, but anything to fix the signature.

Answer (score 2):

```
scala 2.13.0-M5> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object X {
    def map[Output <: AnyVal](f: Int => Output) = 1
    def map[O](f: Int => O)(implicit ev: O <:< AnyRef) = 2
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object X

scala 2.13.0-M5> X.map((x: Int) => x*2)
res0: Int = 1

scala 2.13.0-M5> X.map((x: Int) => "")
res1: Int = 2
```

Comment: I added `ClassTag` context bound in `AnyVal` version, and it seems to work. It seems it is similar to your solution.

Comment: Luckily, there are at least a few ways to do anything in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a typeclass for that `map` method.

Using your exact example:

```
trait MyTC[Output]{
  def map(f: Int => Output): List[Output]
}

object MyTC{
  def apply[A](a : A)(implicit ev : MyTC[A]) : MyTC[A] = ev 

  implicit def anyRefMyTc[A <: AnyRef] : MyTC[A]  = new MyTC[A]{
    def map(f: Int => A): List[A] = { println("inside sub-AnyRef"); List.empty }
  }
  implicit def anyValMyTc[A <: AnyVal] : MyTC[A] = new MyTC[A]{
    def map(f: Int => A): List[A] = { println("inside sub-AnyVal"); List.empty }
  }
}

import MyTC._

val r1 = Option("Test1")
val r2 = List(5)
val v1 = true
val v2 = 6L

// The functions here are just to prove the point, and don't do anything.
MyTC(r1).map(_ => None)
MyTC(r2).map(_ => List.empty)
MyTC(v1).map(_ => false)
MyTC(v2).map(_ => 10L)
```

That would print:

> inside sub-AnyRef
>   inside sub-AnyRef
>   inside sub-AnyVal
>   inside sub-AnyVal

The advantage of this approach is that, should you then choose to specialise the behaviour further for just some specific type (e.g. say you want to do something specific for `Option[String]`), you can do that easily:

```
// This is added to MyTC object 
implicit val optMyTc : MyTC[Option[String]] = new MyTC[Option[String]]{
    def map(f: Int => Option[String]): List[Option[String]] = { println("inside Option[String]"); List.empty }
  }
```

Then, re-running the code will print:

> inside Option[String]
>   inside sub-AnyRef
>   inside sub-AnyVal
>   inside sub-AnyVal

Comment: How about @ specialized to avoid boxing? I didn't have time to experiment with the AnyVal case.